# File viewer (not manager) with dual pane

Tags: files, file-management

I have multiple papers, in multiple directories. 
let us call the papers A, B, C, D... and I have to write reports often, where I have to answer questions like Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4...

Now, what often happens is, I notice that the answer to Q1 is in, say paper A, G, and K. The answer to Q2 is in B, E, the answer to Q3 is in A, C, D, E and so on.

So I want a software like this:

It has to panels, and a bottom pannel to display additional information. In the two panels, the user can add a symbol/link, which will point to a particular file - can also drag/drop a file on it, and it will capture the files path. Clicking on it will lauch the file, and the user should be able to move the symbols (with the path to file in it) between two panes, but it will not change the location of the file in the HDD.

Does such software exists?